# Implement Semaphore using Monitor.Wait(obj) and Monitor.Pulse(obj)

Tags: c#, semaphore, monitor

I have a following task:

"Ordinary" semaphore

Initialized to the number of available resources.

Operations:

```
request () - waits until the resource is released,
release () - releases the resource,
numberAvailable () - returns number available resources, the n
```

which I tried to implement using `Semaphore` slim:

```
    class Program
    {
        private const int InitialCount = 2;
        private const int MaximumCount = 8;

        static void Main()
        {
            var semaphoreObject = new SemaphoreSlim(InitialCount, MaximumCount);
            var printerObject = new Printer();

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
            {
                int j = i;
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Request(semaphoreObject);
                    printerObject.Print(j);
                    Release(semaphoreObject);
                    NumberAvailable(semaphoreObject);
                });
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void Request(SemaphoreSlim s)
        {
            s.Wait();
        }

        private static void Release(SemaphoreSlim s)
        {
            s.Release();
        }

        private static void NumberAvailable(SemaphoreSlim s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Available resource: {s.CurrentCount}");
        }
    }

    class Printer
    {
        public void Print(int documentToPrint)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Printing document: " + documentToPrint);
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        }
    }
```

However now, I need to do that using Monitor class, so I should create my own semaphore class. However I am a bit lost on how to change that

Answer (score 1):

I will not write the code for you but this is how I would do it

1. Inside the new semaphore class, create a counter.
2. Inside the request method use a monitor to:

   1. Increase the count
3. If the count is the same as the allowed threads, use another monitor to lock a new object
4. At the release

   1. Decrease the count inside the first monitor
   2. Unlock the second monitor if it was locked.

Bear in mind that this is not the best way to go. Use the internal type for production code. This is only to get you started for an exercise or such.